# Get SubjectKeyIdentifier and AuthorityKeyIdentifier from certificate

Tags: c, openssl

I am parsing a file that contains a Document Signer certificate (SOD file of an ePassport).

How can I get the certificate's SKI or AKI using openssl API (not CLI)?

Thanks!

Comment: You're talking about the C functions in libcrypto and libssl?

Comment: Yes, sorry, unwashed referring to those.

Comment: Writing a C program is usually rather verbose.  You ought to show what you've got so far in order to constrain the scope of your question to something answerable.

Comment: The source code to OpenSSL's `x509` subcommand is located at [`<openssl src>/apps/x509.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/x509.c). Pay attention to `print_x509v3_exts` because SPKI and AKI are extensions.